# armadillo C++: Cannot write float 2D array to fmat

Tags: c++, arrays, armadillo

I have a 2 float  2D array and 1D array. I want to create fmat variable and write  2D array to it and then 1D to vector and then solve it using Gaussion elimination. When I try write 2d Array to variable I got result: `[matrix 1:0]` in the other Segmentation fault

```
fmat A;
for(int i=0; i<elements+1; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<elements+1; ++j)
        A << globalMatrix[i][j];
    A << endr;
}

cout<<"MATRIX\n\n";
A.print();

fvec B(elements+1);

for(int i=0;i<elements+1;++i)
    B=loadVec[i];

cout<<B;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fmat` class is not a stream, so you can't use the `<<` operation in a loop.  Instead, simply copy the elements across.  You will also need to bear in mind that Armadillo stores matrices in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) (for compatibility with LAPACK).  See the Armadillo documentation for more information about [accessing elements](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access).

```
fmat A(elements+1, elements+1, fill::zeros);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<elements+1; ++i)
for(unsigned int j=0; j<elements+1; ++j)
  {
  A(i,j) = globalMatrix[i][j];
  }

A.print("A:");


fvec B(elements+1);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<elements+1; ++i)
  {
  B(i) = loadVec[i];
  }

B.print("B:");
```